# MariaDB not allow host machine connection when using docker in wsl2

Tags: docker, mariadb, wsl-2

I was created user in mariadb already, but when I used HeidiSQL in windows10, it still told me my host machine not allowed to connect db server.

What's wrong?

I have seen some people say that the network connection of wsl2 is a little troublesome, does it have anything to do with this?

Comment: What is the exact mariadb version and error? Are the container logs showing MariaDB running?

Comment: It is the latest version, and the container states is running